# Using Analytical Perlin Noise Derivatives on a 3D Surface

Tags: math, 3d, derivative, procedural-generation, perlin-noise

I'm trying to learn about creating and using analytical derivatives of perlin noise to quickly generate normals. I've been experimenting with code from one of [Catlike Coding's tutorials](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/noise-derivatives/), and while I get the idea of assuming the 'up' axis is 1 and normalizing when sampling on a 2D plane I can't find any information about what to do when sampling on a 3D surface.

This is what I'm after (this uses central difference normals):
[image]

And this is what those normals look like in world space:
[image]

But the derivatives I'm getting look like this:
[image]

It seems like they might be relative to the surface of the undisplaced sphere, so would that mean I need to reorient them with the undisplaced sphere's normals? And how would I turn the derivatives into normals after doing that?

Comment: You haven't show any of your *own* code. If the tutorial code doesn't work, you must have made your own adaptations to it.

Comment: I know this an old question but, if anyone ends up here with the same problem at the third image, just do this: `vec3 normal = vec3(normalize(vertex.xyz - (derivative.xyz * 0.45)));`. That will give you the correct vertex normal.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a solution. What I did was construct a rotation quaternion using the world-space surface normal, rotate the derivative vector by the inverse of that rotation, then turn it into a normal as you would on a plane and rotate it back with the normal rotation again.

[Using the derivatives as surface normals now looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R29y9.jpg)

[And now mixing octaves based on the slope of the normals looks like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHCxQ.png)

[And this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHAnF.png)

[And this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5dr2.png)

And here's some of the code that finds the normal and slope:

```
float3 qRotateVector(float3 v, float4 q) {
    float3 t = 2.0 * cross(q.xyz, v);
    return v + q.w * t + cross(q.xyz, t);
}

float4 qFromToRotation(float3 v) {
    float3 up = float3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    float d = dot(up, v);

    if (d < -0.999999) {
        return float4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    }
    else if (d > 0.999999) {
        return float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    else {
        return normalize(float4(cross(up, v), d + 1.0));
    }
}

float noiseSlope(float3 derivatives, float3 normal) {
    float4 noiseRotation = qFromToRotation(normal);
    float3 derivativeNormal = qRotateVector(derivatives, float4(-noiseRotation.xyz, noiseRotation.w));
    return abs(dot(normalize(float3(-derivativeNormal.x, 1.0, -derivativeNormal.z)), float3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)));
}
```

(I originally tried using matrices but I kept having problems with gimbal locking)

After I experimented with that I discovered [Inigo Quilez](http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/morenoise/morenoise.htm) also has an example of mixing by slope by dividing the height with 1 + dot(derivative.yz, derivative.yz) instead of rotating the noise, which I'm going to try messing with too.